# How to read XML document and display the output as string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument, xmlreader

consider my source file looks like this.

```
        <Content xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1x82c78xx920">
            <first>Hello World.This is Fisrt field</first>
            <second>Hello World.This is second field</second>
   </Content>
```

I want to write a code, which read this xml document from a location and display it as string.

```
  say name of the xml file is helloworld.xml.
  Location: D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml.
```

I have tried the following, but i was unable to do it.

```
            XmlDocument contentxml = new XmlDocument();
            contentxml.LoadXml(@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
            Response.Write("<BR>" + contentxml.ToString());
```

Response.write is displaying nothing. Correct me if i missed any thing. Its not creating any component and error is coming.

I have also tried this,

```
            XmlDocument contentxml = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                 contentxml.LoadXml(@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
             }
            catch (XmlException exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            contentxml.WriteTo(xw);
            Response.Write("<BR>" + sw.ToString());
```

But i did not find the any output.

I want to read a XML file from a location and display it as it is as string.

Can anyone help on this.

Thank you,
Muzimil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `OuterXml` property:

```
Response.Write("<BR>" + contentxml.OuterXml);
```

Also you are loading a *file* not xml so use

```
  contentxml.Load(@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
```

instead of

```
  contentxml.LoadXml(@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to deserialize the XML at all?  Why not just read it as a text file?  Something like..

```
String text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
Response.Write(text);
```

With appropriate error handling obviously..

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the `XDocument` class:

```
//load the document from file
var doc = XDocument.Load("..."); //== path to the file

//write the xml to the screen
Response.Write(doc.ToString());
```

If you want to use an `XmlDocument` instead, you would want to use `Load` instead `LoadXml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply write a file to the output, you can do [Response.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (@"D:\abcd\cdef\all\helloworld.xml");
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sample.xml"));
txtData.Text = text;
```